# GCM demo application not sending notifications to physical device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I imported the GCM-client into android studio and ran it on my phone. It's very simple, where it has 2 buttons [send] and [clear]. When I hit send, it populates the textView below it saying "Sent Message"
but I don't receive a push notification. What am I missing here?

I used http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html to test my see if my device was registered and it came back a success. It gave me this message:

```
{"multicast_id":9190727201254576977,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1421901326474839%921c249af9fd7ecd"}]}
```

I've got notifications to work using a localhost:8080 apache ant server. But they only work in my emulator. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, if you want get GCM notification on your physical device you need to online server. By using localhost its work only on emulator. So you have to move your link to online server.

Comment: a couple of things you need to be careful about on the Google Developer Console, there are API keys for Server Applications and Browsers, here there are options to allow 'any IP Address' and 'any referers' , need to enable them and crosscheck the key you are using. Also, you get a response when you Send the message, check that for any errors

Comment: @Shane. I already have a live server and it's a no go. It's at 68.84.84.84:8080. And I've edited the SERVER_URL in CommonUtilities.java to match.